# How can I calculate my catnip output for a cold winter?

Tags: kittens-game

I like to always have my catnip income always be positive.  That being the case, the worst case scenario I have to look at is the *Winter (cold)* which displays a **-90%** by the income.  I'd like to be able do this with only what is in the info box (Base, Structures, Season, Job output, Demand).

[image: Catnip box]

Using the numbers in the info box, how can I determine what my cold winter output would be?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can find it out by putting the variables in the resource formula from the [wiki](http://bloodrizer.ru/games/kittens/wiki/index.php?page=Resources&redirect=no):

> perTick = (building output * season modifier + job output * upgrades * happiness) * building % effects + automatic effects - consumption * consumption % effects

or to simplify for catnip in your specific case and naming the variables as seen in the tooltip:

> perTick = (base * season modifier + job output * happiness) * structures - demand

Comment: This doesn't seem to work properly.  Replacing variables from your function with what I had (happiness was 101% at the time): `(10 * 1.5 + 4.590 * 1.01) * 1.35 - 21.325 != +190.00`

Comment: @Batophobia Is you display showing the per-second rate? That looks very high for a per-tick rate.

Comment: @murgatroid99 I was, thanks for the tip.

Comment: It's very possible that my "simplified" formula is missing some variables, so if it doesn't work, I will edit it out.